# composer require specific git commit that hasn't been merged to branch

Tags: git, composer-php

In my project I require a package using `composer`. This morning I learned there was a merged pull-request overnight however there was a bad function left in a class of the code which breaks it. Someone fixed the error and made a commit but it hasn't been merged to the `master` branch yet.

So I update `composer.json` and set the `sha1` like this:

```
"require": {
    "vendor/package": "dev-master#d0d6b33897e1739c55a338fdd0a544bfe5a10721"
}
```

and run `composer update` and get

```
d0d6b33897e1739c55a338fdd0a544bfe5a10721 is gone (history was rewritten?), recovered by checking out 33e68f9cec94d52f40192c576d7441ea12852b99
```

Is what I want to do possible on a commit that hasn't been merged? Forgive my ignorance if this is stupid - relatively new to composer. I could just manually remove the code until it's pushed but I ask mainly out of curiosity.

Comment: Have you tried just specifying the commit SHA, and not also the branch name?

Comment: That won't work as per the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess (without actually knowing) that you cannot include a commit from a branch that this commit is not on. If that commit is not merged to master, it cannot be included with it's hash while at the same time specifying that you want "dev-master".

You should specify that other branch the fix is on instead. If that branch is yet to be moved into the repository that is known to Packagist/Composer, you probably have to also include the other repository of the actual committer to enable Composer to find that branch and it's commit.

On the other hand: Why bother with unstable master branches? Have you considered requiring a stable tagged version instead? Life is so much easier then (and I do know that for reasons I don't understand, some repository managers avoid tagging versions, thus making everyone's life a little bit more miserable, but hopefully it serves their use case then).

Comment: Actually what you say makes sense, I should have thought to try that. Either way eventually it was pushed and all is good again but it seemed an interesting question nonetheless. But yes in most situations I would agree completely with you, just require a stable tagged release.

Answer (score 0):

The example below uses a bitbucket example, but you could easily do the same with github

```
{
    "name": "YOUR_VENDOR_NAME/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME",
    "description": "PPROJECT DESCRIPTION",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "authors": [{
      "name": "YOUR_NAME",
      "email": "YOUR_EMAIL"
    }],
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [{
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "YOUR_PACKAGE_VENDOR_NAME/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "type": "library",
        "source": {
          "type": "git",
          "url": "git@bitbucket.org:BITBUCKET_USERNAME/REPOSITORY_SLUG.git",
          "reference": "COMMIT_HASH"
        }
      }
    }],
    "require": {
      "YOUR_PACKAGE_VENDOR_NAME/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME": "0.0.1"
    }
}
```